# Restoring GridstackJS Panels with Content (e.g. Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, gridstack

I am building a Dashboard where you are able to add, delete, move and resize Panels within a grid using GridstackJS. I am filling these Panels with different things. In this Example I am using a Highchart. For saving and restoring the position and Size of the Panels I use the standard serialization of GridstackJS.

My problem now is to save and restore the Content inside the Panels.

Is there an elegant way to save the Content and apply it to the correct Panel when restoring?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrOsCoRe/sa7mz1ug/5/)

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@0.5.5/dist/gridstack.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@0.5.5/dist/gridstack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@0.5.5/dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@0.5.5/dist/gridstack.jQueryUI.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<button id="save-grid" class="btn btn-primary">Save Grid</button>
                <button id="load-grid" class="btn btn-primary">Load Grid</button>
                <button id="delete-grid" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Grid</button>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="grid-stack ui-droppable">
            <div class="dragbox grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable" data-gs-id="draggable">
                <h2 class="dragbox-header">Chart 1</h2>
                <div class="dragbox-content">
                    <div class="text-center"> Item 1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dragbox grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable" data-gs-id="draggable">
                <h2 class="dragbox-header">Chart 2</h2>
                <div class="dragbox-content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dragbox grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable" data-gs-id="draggable" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
                <h2 class="dragbox-header" id="testChartHeader">Chart 3</h2>
                <div class="text-center" id="testChart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dragbox {
    margin: 5px 2px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.dragbox-header {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-family: Verdana;
    cursor: move;
    position: relative;
}

.dragbox-content {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#testChart {
    height: 200px;
}

.placeholder {
    background: lightgray;
    border: 1px dashed #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        draggable: {handle: '.dragbox-header', scroll: false, appendTo: 'body'},
        placeholderClass: "placeholder",
        acceptWidgets: true,
        cellHeight: 60
    };
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
    new function () {
      this.serializedData = [
      ];

      this.grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');

      this.loadGrid = function () {
        this.grid.removeAll();
        var items = GridStackUI.Utils.sort(this.serializedData);
        items.forEach(function (node, i) {
          this.grid.addWidget($('<div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable" data-gs-id="draggable"><div class="dragbox grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle"><div class="dragbox-header">Chart ' + (i + 1) + '</div></div></div>'), node);
        }, this);
        return false;
      }.bind(this);

      this.saveGrid = function () {
        this.serializedData = $('.grid-stack > .grid-stack-item').map(function (i, el) {
          el = $(el);
          var node = el.data('_gridstack_node');
          return {
            x: node.x,
            y: node.y,
            width: node.width,
            height: node.height
          };
        }).toArray();

        return false;
      }.bind(this);

      this.clearGrid = function () {
        this.grid.removeAll();
        return false;
      }.bind(this);

      $('#save-grid').click(this.saveGrid);
      $('#load-grid').click(this.loadGrid);
      $('#delete-grid').click(this.clearGrid);
    };
  });
var chart = Highcharts.chart('testChart', {
    chart: {
        animation: false,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false,
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});

$('.grid-stack').on('change', function(event, items) {
    var chartContainer = chart.renderTo;
    $(chartContainer).css(
        'height',
        $(chartContainer.parentElement).height() - $('#testChartHeader').height()
    );

    chart.reflow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a chart again in the `loadGrid` function:

```
    this.loadGrid = function() {
        this.grid.removeAll();
        var items = GridStackUI.Utils.sort(this.serializedData);
        items.forEach(function(node, i) {
            this.grid.addWidget($('<div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable" data-gs-id="draggable"><div class="dragbox grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle"><div class="dragbox-header">Chart ' + (i + 1) + '</div>' + (i === 2 ? '<div id="testChart"></div>' : '') + '</div></div>'), node);
        }, this);

        chart = createChart();

        return false;
    }.bind(this);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pjy8b950/

Comment: This does kind of work in this very simple Example. But as soon as I have different Chart Types with different Series which are getting created dynamicaly I get the Problem that the loadGrid function doesnt know what kind of Chart with what kind of data right?

Comment: That's right, to solve this, you can store the atual options. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/psbgjq3d/

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response and Happy new Year. 
So far it is working fine if I only got one Chart. Since this aims to dynamicly add and remove many Charts I want the ChartOptions for every independent Chart safed to the correct Panel when saving and when restoring get the correct ChartOptions for the Panels. Is there an easy and effective way of doing it?

Comment: Hi @BrOsCoRe, The same for you! Could you provide me with some simple example where the problem is present?

Comment: Basically is the question can I save the ChartOptions to the exact right Node? Because at the moment its hard coded that the Highchart appears in Panel 3. But when I Move Panel 3 to the Front and save the Grid I want the Highchart to appear in the Front when reloading.

Comment: You probably need to store options for each chart in a different variable.